# How to swap tensor indices without permutation?

Tags: matrix, tensors, index

Say I have a tensor of rank R, How to swap $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ tensor index? I do not want to use TensorTranspose because it requires to write down the entire permutation, i.e. TensorTranspose[T,{1,2,3,...,j,...i,...,R}], but for my application I don't know before hand what are the numerical values of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know what the numerical values of $i$ and $j$, then it will be hard to implement the index swap. However, it is easy to programmatically implement the index list as an argument for `TensorTranspose`:

```
Permute[Range[1, 10], Cycles[{{2, 5}}]]

(* => {1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

Thus, you could do something like

```
twoWayTranspose[T_, {i_, j_}] := TensorTranspose[T,
                                    Permute[Range[ArrayDepth[T]], Cycles[{{i, j}}]]
                                   ]
```

Comment: TensorTranspose understands Cycles notation. Hence you can define twoWayTranspose[T_, {i_, j_}] := TensorTranspose[T, Cycles[{{i, j}}]].